Explicit upper bound on norm of Hardy-Littlewood maximal function from $L^p$ to $L^p$
It is well known that, given the Hardy-Littlewood maximal function
$$ Mf(x) = \sup_{r>0} \frac{1}{|B_r (x)|} \int_{B_r (x)} |f(y)| dy$$
the maximal function is continuous from $L^p$ to $L^p$ if $p>1$. Stein and Stromberg proved in 1982 that
$$ ||Mf||_{p} \leq C_p ||f||_p$$
with $C_p$ depending only on $p$ and not on the dimension $n$ of the problem. If you look at the paper I was mentioning, titled "Behavior of maximal functios in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for large $n$ ", they also give an explicit dimension-dependent constant which is $C \frac{p}{p-1} \sqrt{n}$. However, I haven't found an explicit expression, or bound for either $C_p$ in the dimension independent bound or $C$ for the dimension dependent one. Is it known?
